# What is the use case for multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply()?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, apply, python-multiprocessing

I have been trying to grasp multiprocessing (not multithreading) in Python for the past few days and don't understand the purpose of [multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply).

Being the first method of the `Pool` class, I would assume that it is the one to use by default, but it seems to be useless in the multiprocessing context. The documentation is confusing and very brief and says:

> It blocks until the result is ready. Given this blocks, apply_async() is better suited for performing work in parallel.

1. Does it block only the process that was created for it? If yes, then that would not be a problem for mostly CPU-bound processes.

> Additionally, func is only executed in one of the workers of the pool.

2. Why would something like this be even in the `Pool` class? When I first read it, I thought I was misunderstanding it, but it really seems that only one process is started. **Why would anyone want this behavior if he is using a class specifically for *multiprocessing***?

I know that there is `apply_async` and it seems to work, but I am still left with a feeling that I must be missing something about `apply` and  I want to clear it up.

I am using code similar to this:

```
with Pool(16) as pool:
    pool_results = []
    for city in cities:
        for street in streets:
            for house in houses:
                for room in rooms:
                    pool_results.append(pool.apply_async(func=simulate, args=(city, street, house, room)))
    [result.wait() for result in pool_results]
```

Comment: You've misunderstood some things (like when processes are started or how many are started), but `Pool.apply` is indeed pretty useless.

Comment: Think of `Pool.apply` the same way you think about `Thread.run` (when not overriding it) -- as a building block that's used under-the-hood to compose the behavior you eventually want, as opposed to something that actually provides that behavior itself. One of the things that falls out of Python not having private methods is that you get to see everything on the surface -- just because a method exists doesn't mean it's there with direct end-user invocation in mind.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I am not familiar with the specifics of `Thread.run` but if it is really a building block then why would it be part of a "high-level" API? Seems like a bad and confusing design choice.

Comment: If you're building a high-level API, one typically builds helper functions to support it. They end up there as part of the support structure _for_ the high-level calls; but aren't high-level calls themselves. My point is that there isn't really a problem here. Nothing obliges you to use calls you don't care about, and if they came in helpful to the person who was building the calls you _do_ care about, why argue that that person was negligent?

Comment: Bottom line is that I see this question falling into the same category discussed in [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design), insofar as it's not about any problem you're actually facing and need to know how to fix.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Shouldn't it be "private" then, starting with *__*?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I spend several hours trying to get *apply()* to work and only then realized that it does not do what the name is suggesting it does. Therefore this question might benefit other people facing the same problem. The title could be changed to "Is ....apply() really useless and should be ignored 99% of the time?"

Comment: Unless the goal was to allow folks to subclass and override, as with the `Thread.run` example. That requires getting into the designer's head, though, and that's not what we do here (in on-topic questions); we fix _practical, answerable questions about problems people actually face_ (to so-very-slightly paraphrase https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: It sounds like you already solved your actual problem.

Comment: ...I'll also note that a synchronous `apply` gives one the ability to have a thread inside one process block on something happening in a pool member in a different process. That can be handy if you want to build your UI framework in a shared-memory threading model, while your actual work happens under a multiprocessing model. It's not unheard of for folks to prefer threading when they can get away with it; using multiprocessing to move work that would hold the GIL out-of-process lets one get away with writing traditional thread-based code when one otherwise couldn't.